# How to retrieve post data form ajax request on symfony 4?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, xmlhttprequest

I'm setting up a form. All data are retrieved on js file. How can I send this data to a symfony controller ?

I have tried : `$request->get('values');` and `$request->request->all();` but none of this actually works.

Controller PHP :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/dem", name="dem")
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
       if (isset($request->isXmlHttpRequest())) {
          dump(json_decode($request->get('values')));
       }
       return $this->render('dem/index.html.twig');
    }
```

JS File :

```
   console.log(values) // response: json of an array of elements 
   $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: {values: values},
      success: data => {
         console.log('data : ');
         console.log(data);
      }
   });
```

HTML Form :

```
    <form id="dem" name="dem" action="{{ path('dem') }}" method="POST" class="w-75 m-auto">
```

I expect an output of my array of elements

Thx all :}

Comment: try to display  -- dump(json_decode($request->request->get('values')));

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `$request->getContent();`, it return the raw json of your request. After you have to unserialize it.

```
$parametersAsArray = [];
if ($content = $request->getContent()) {
    $parametersAsArray = json_decode($content, true);
}
```

Comment: Good idea, i just tried that but no result `$request->getContent()` is empty

Comment: If you add to your request this HEADER `'Content-Type': 'application/json' `

Comment: where do you want to add this line ? 

before the dump ?

Comment: in your js file

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct in controller. Although, you have to do some minor changes in your js file:

```
$.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        data: {
                            values: values
                        },
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                           console.log('data : ');
                           console.log(data);
                        }
```